# How do I rotate a page/table in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I have a label template, and I wish to print it in landscape view. I can certainly rotate the text in each cell to accomplish my aim, however, I'm then typing everything sideways. It would be very convenient if I could also rotate the page to landscape (along with the table), so that I'm now using the labels naturally in the rotated orientation. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change the page orientation of the document itself first, then resize the elements. I'm afraid I don't think there is an automated way of rotating all elements to keep their orientation, you'll probably have to move them around yourself.

[image]

An alternative solution would be creating a new label template in landscape mode:

click the 'Label' field ("Microsoft, 1/2 Letter" etc):

[image]

Select the label you want to base it on, then click 'new label':

[image]

Set the page size to A4 Landscape (or whichever other format you want, if not specified use 'custom'), and add the number of rows and columns available on your label sheet.

[image]

This'll result in a label template you can keep reusing.

Comment: Just realised... You're talking about labels, do you use specific label templates? i.e. through mailings -> labels, and then selecting whichever company and type made your label sheet? These work differently.

Comment: That is what I'm working with, but I'm using address labels, and they expect a portrait feed with horizontal labels. I want to use the label in a vertical orientation. I think you're right though, the only way is to move everything manually.

Comment: There might be a different way of going about this - you'll have to move your labels over, but you could create a new landscape template yourself. I'll add to the post.